# Invalid procedure call or argument in Pivot table creation

Tags: vba, dynamic, range, pivot-table

i have a hard time finding the solution for this error, i checked many posts but to no avail, it stays that there is a problem with this line

```
Set ptable = pCache.CreatePivotTable( _
                            TableDestination:=DestSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                            TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                            DefaultVersion:=6)
```

so here is the code

```vb
Sub TestPivot()
            Dim mySourceData As String
            'Declare Variables 
            Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
            Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
            'Declare Variales  row and column 
            Dim FirstRow As Long
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim FirstCol As Long
            Dim LastCol As Long
            Dim ptable As PivotTable
            Dim pCache As PivotCache
            
            'Set/Define Source and Destination Variables
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set SourceSheet = Worksheets("W")
                Set DestSheet = Worksheets("Pivot_W")
            End With
            'identify first row and first column of source data cell range
            FirstRow = 2
            FirstCol = 2
            'Find last row and last column of source data cell range
            'And obtain address of source data cell range
            With Sheets("W").Range("A:N")
                LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                mySourceData = .Range(.Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
            End With

            'Insert Pivot Table
                Set pCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SourceSheet.Name & "!" & mySourceData, Version:=6)
                Set ptable = pCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DestSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6)
        
            If Not IsEmpty(ptable) Then
            MsgBox "non vide"
            End If
            With DestSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Magasin")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            End With
End Sub
```

I appreciate your help and thank you for reading my post.